# Adverb to describe one's career?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adverbs

I am writing a document where I need to describe a decision I'm making that is beneficial both to my finances and to furthering my career. I'm more partial to using two `-ly` adverbs to match the rhythm of the rest of the document. The first is obvious: *financially*. I am struggling with the second: an adverb to describe my career. *Professionally* came to mind, but that sounds a bit too stiff, and I would like to place the emphasis on the learning opportunity. Is there a more apt word? Or should I drop the `-ly` words altogether and try others?

Comment: Could you explain how *professionally* is stiffer than *financially*?  They seem equally stiff to me.

Comment: @Ed A good point. In the situational context, however, I feel that _professionally_ has dubious personal undertones. The emphasis is on the opportunity.

Comment: I like "financially and professionally" and don't see a problem. Otherwise you'll need something like, "good for my finances and my career," etc.

Comment: If you're keen to avoid being 'stiff', how about saying it'll improve your bank balance and your job prospects? Too informal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **[vocationally](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vocationally)**, if that fits for you (even without the `ly`) - but there is no *real* surrounding context here, we're going to be putting words in your mouth, so to speak.

Comment: I really like this word.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't see a problem with the word *professionally* in the case you describe, the term ***professional growth*** might come off a bit softer. For example, "This decision benefits me financially and offers opportunities for professional growth." I believe that *professional growth* suggests a desire for self-improvement. It avoids some possible negative interpretation of *professional benefits* that I think you're worried about, such as a reckless pursuit of titles and dollars.

Comment: Nicely put. I agree with you in that *professionally* wouldn't exactly raise my hackles, but OP says he has a problem with it, so that's out before we start. Like you, I think **professional growth** does indeed suggest a laudable desire to better oneself, steering away thoughts of attempting to climb the greasy pole.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> Scholarly

if that helps.

Comment: That's actually an adjective, no?

Comment: @Ryan Reich Haha, good catch. I didn't really put much thought into this, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Clarifying the context would be beneficial, for us. Can you phrase the sentence you're trying to write?

**essentially**?

Comment: I don't wish to seem  rude, but it's not obvious to me how this answer (or indeed any other answers or comments you've made here on EL&U) will enhance anyone's understanding or command of the English language. Your contributory style might be more at home in a chat forum.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No you're completely correct. Thanks. _nb. only deceit for the sake of diplomacy & offence taken are rude. Thoughtful criticism is always complimentary even if not intended to be._